# How to set icon from image(image in gallery)

Tags: android

In my app I want to create icon from image.
So after first run app will open gallery and user must choose an image.
Then I will resize it and will save to app-folder.
But how to can I set this png to icon?

```
result.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE,
            Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(this, R.drawable.icon));
```

Here I must use icon from resource. 
Is another way to set icon from image?

Maybe something it:

```
int imgID = getResources().getIdentifier("/data/data/ 
com.blogspot.vsvydenko/app_thumbnails/fullBrowser.PNG", "drawable", 
getPackageName());
```

But I always got imgID == 0 ((

Thank.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of a larger image (larger than icon size), you typically want to use a [ContentProvider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html) with getBlob().

From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html):

> If a query can return binary data, such as an image or sound, the data
>   may be directly entered in the table or the table entry for that data
>   may be a string specifying a content: URI that you can use to get the
>   data. In general, smaller amounts of data (say, from 20 to 50K or
>   less) are most often directly entered in the table and can be read by
>   calling Cursor.getBlob()

I suggest you read through the provided docs for ContentProvider.  This may solve your problem.

As for resizing the image, for displaying, resizing, and storing images in Android, I suggest you check out the [2D graphics tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html).  It may help you understand what you need to do to perform this task correctly.

Hope this helped!